# Displaying a WPF Window by name

Tags: c#, wpf

Project A contains a WPF Window (Data Entry Form) with a stack panel of commands that launch various reports.  The menu is a dynamically built list from a database.  What I’m attempting to do is launch the corresponding WPF window based on the CommandText associated with the menu choice.   I’d like to create a single function that accepts the name of the WPF Window (CommandText) and launches a new instance of the window by name.

I’ve found examples of how to launch methods on classes, but can’t seem to find a method that works with a window.  I know it can be done with a switch and just map all the windows, but there are 60-70 and I was trying to avoid bloat.

I’m failed repeatedly trying to use the `TypeOf` and `Activator.CreateInstance`.  Suggestions? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
string windowClass = "CreateWindow.MyWindow";
Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(windowClass);
ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance(null, windowClass);
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Show");
method.Invoke(handle.Unwrap(), null);
```

The code above assumes that your window is called "CreateWindow.MyWindow" (with namespace prefix) and that the type "CreateWindow.MyWindow" is in the currently executing assembly.

Comment: I falsely assumed the Namespace and Project had the same name.  Changed the namespace prefix and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Activator works fine for me. What error do you have? Try if below code will work for you

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window wnd = (Window)CreateWindow("WpfApplication1.Window2");
    wnd.Show();

}

public object CreateWindow(string fullClassName)
{
    Assembly asm = this.GetType().Assembly;

    object wnd = asm.CreateInstance(fullClassName);
    if (wnd == null)
    {
        throw new TypeLoadException("Unable to create window: " + fullClassName);
    }
    return wnd;
}
```